# как переназначить ссылку this

Tags: java

```
public class Temp {
    void f (){
       Temp u= new Temp();
       this=u;//так нельзя
    }
}
```

Как сделать чтобы методе класса можно было перекинуть ссылку объекта на созданный новый объект.

Comment: а что Вы таким образом хотите сделать?

Comment: Класс Temp я хочу модифицировать : изменить переменные и т.д . И чтобы не перебирать каждую, мне легче создать новый класс

Comment: в целом так нельзя, но можно наоборот: сделать метод, который инициализирует класс и вызывать его как из конструктора, так и из этого Вашего метода

Comment: Вы бы не могли показать на примере кода,заранее спасибо

Comment: я пишу с телефона, перенесте в метод f() все содержимое конструктора, и вызовите в конструкторе иетод f()

Comment: А в чём смысл, почему бы просто не сделать `new Temp()` на ту ссылку в программе в которой храниться уже ненужный объект? Может приведёте более подробный пример?

Answer (score 1):

this это указатель на текущий объект, связанный с Temp, у которого был вызван метод f(), если вам нужно вернуть новый объект, установите возвращаемое значение, вместо void.

```
public class Temp {
        Temp f (){
            Temp u= new Temp();
            return u;
        }
    }
```